# Vertical dotted line in an equation

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I am trying to get vertical dotted/dashed lines in between of equation. I used \vdots and got this, but I want the dotted line to be bigger.

Following is what I've done.

```
 \begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
         1|2|\dots|r \ \ \ \  r+1|r+2|\dots|k \vdots \ \ \ \ k+1|k+2|\dots|k+r
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
```

This is what I've got as output. [image: output]

I want something like this with dotted or dashed lines (anything is fine)
[image: what I want]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take the definition of `\vdots` from `fontmath.ltx` and adapt it:

```
% from fontmath.ltx
\DeclareRobustCommand\vdots{%
  \vbox{%
    \baselineskip4\p@ \lineskiplimit\z@
    \kern6\p@
    \hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}
  }%
}
```

You want more dots and that they are centered with respect to the formula axis, so the first step is to change `\vbox` into `\vcenter`. Now add as many dots you like (here nine) and make the symbol a math relation to go along with `\mid`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for 'equation*' env.

\newcommand{\tallvdots}{%
  \vcenter{%
    \baselineskip=4pt \lineskiplimit=0pt
    \hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}
    \hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}
    \hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
1 \mid 2 \mid \dots \mid r 
\qquad  % or '\quad' if you prefer
r+1 \mid r+2 \mid \dots \mid k 
\mathrel{\tallvdots}
\qquad  % or '\quad' if you prefer
k+1 \mid k+2 \mid \dots \mid k+r
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can define `\tallvdots` by:

```
\def\tallvdots{%
   \mathrel{\vcenter{\offinterlineskip
      \kern-1.4ex\hbox{$\vdots$}\kern-.7ex\hbox{$\vdots$}%
   }}%
}
```

No array, no rotatebox. Only two `\vdots` one above second. The `\kerns` are here because the height of the default `\vdots` character has bad metric.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

[image]

Note that in addition to creating and using a macro called `\tallvdots`, I've also replaced all instances of `|` with `\mid`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for 'equation*' env.
\usepackage{graphicx} % for 'rotatebox' macro

% to be used in math mode:
\newcommand\xvdots{\vcenter{\hbox{$\vdots$}}}
\newcommand\tallvdots{% 
  \mathrel{\begin{array}{@{}c@{}} 
             \xvdots \\ \rotatebox{180}{$\xvdots$} 
           \end{array}
          }
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
1 \mid 2 \mid \dots \mid r 
\qquad  % or '\quad' if you prefer
r+1 \mid r+2 \mid \dots \mid k 
\tallvdots 
\qquad  % or '\quad' if you prefer
k+1 \mid k+2 \mid \dots \mid k+r
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I want

Comment: @Sergio - Please go ahead and (a) unaccept the answer I posted and (b) accept [@egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/647270/5001) instead. His method is not only more elegant than mine, but it also solves a (somewhat hidden) problem with my method. (My method produces a solution whose total height and depth actually exceeds the visible height and depth.) Thanks.